# Add custom element to home menu item in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, menu, overriding, joomla2.5

What i'm trying to do is quite simple as concept, but i'm not that good with php and the joomla framework.
Currently the *home* menu-item is generated like this:

```
<li class="item-101 current active">
  <a class="hide-text" href="#some-link">Home</a>
</li>
```

What i'd like to achieve is to insert an `<i>` element inside ***only*** the *home* menu-item, something like this:

```
<li class="item-101 current active">
  <a class="hide-text" href="#some-link"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a>
</li>
```

How can i achieve this? I'm using Joomla! 2.5 atm

I guess it's possible do something like "if this menu-item is the home link then add this code inside the `<a>` tags" but i really don't know how to do it, my php is not strong enough :P

**Note:** 
i'm doing this to achieve a simple home-icon instead of the litteral *home* menu-item.

 As the classes syntax could suggest, i'm using the *twitter bootstrap* css-framework, but i've implemented the *Icomoon* font-set (as in joomla 3.0) instead  of the *tbs Glyph-icons* sprites images.

 Unfortunately, using font-based icons, text rules are applied to the icons also, and that is the reason i'm trying to insert a custom element inside the `<a>` tag, so that i can override the `hide-text` class hiding the home-icon.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look in the template file of the menu module.

/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php

The template builds the HTML for the menu module.

I just checked how it works in Joomla 2.5, and in the /modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php template the list is build. If you want to add  to only the home link you'll have to add a little bit of code. Something like this :

```
if($item->home == '1'){ $item->title = '<i class="icon-home"></i>' . $item->title; };
```

Insert this just under the foreach loop and have a go, it should look something like this :

```
foreach ($list as $i => &$item) :
    // THIS ADDS THE <i> to only the HOME LINK
    if($item->home == '1'){ $item->title = '<i class="icon-home"></i>' . $item->title; }; 

    $class = 'item-'.$item->id;
    if ($item->id == $active_id) {
        $class .= ' current';
    }
```

Good Luck ;)

Comment: you may be right, but editing core Joomla fles is a bad idea. I would recommend making a template override before adding this code ;)

Comment: Dear @Lodder, I am right, atleast I'm sure of it in Joomla 2.5.

Feel free to augment my advice with a detailed tutorial on how to properly add template overrides to a joomla template. ;)

Comment: This indeed worked and the mention to the override by @Lodder is right too, mixed this is working really nice!
The `title` trick is pretty nifty, thank you!

Comment: @Gruber "One is glad to be of service"

Comment: Nice solution, thank you Mark. The suggestion from @Lodder re template overrides is good. To do this copy SITE/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php to SITE/templates/SITE-TEMPLATE/html/mod_menu/default.php . You will
probably need to create this second mod_menu directory. Once you've done this, make the edits on this new default.php file

Answer (score 0):

I have been following this guide as well, (Thanks Gruber and Mark Vink) but using the glyphicons instead of IcoMoon.  I found there to be a syntax error in the example above.  The version hat worked for me was

```
foreach ($list as $i => &$item) { 

if($item->home == '1')$item->title = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>' .$item->title; 
$class = 'item-' . $item->id
```

etc...

Comment: But having done all of this, I still cannot hide the link text, which I do not need.  Please is there a workaround for this?