# Font awesome icons in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, icons, inline, navbar

I am trying to get my font-awesome icons to display in the navbar. The navbar is generated and controlled from the Joomla backend however and the 'Title' does not allow for taglines.

The tag I am trying to implement on only one navbar object is like this:

```
<li><a href="/donate"><i class="icon-medkit"></i> Donate!</a></li>
```

Has anyone any experience or any ideas as to how to implement this and get the icon onto the navbar button?

Currently the menu item looks like this:

```
<li><a href="/donate">Donate!</li>
```

This is in Joomla, so a solution isn't as easy as manually editing my hard navbar code (unfortunately). I may require a script to add it to the menu?

Comment: Check out 'Add spans to menu items': http://www.joomlabamboo.com/joomla-extensions/jb-type-joomla-typography-plugin

Answer (score 0):

This method worked well for me on a Joomla 2.5 site:
[Add custom element to home menu item in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073438/add-custom-element-to-home-menu-item-in-joomla/13073863#13073863)

Good luck!