# joomla 2.5 and template with font awesome

Tags: joomla2.5

probably a stupid question, but I can not figure out where to go to give the name of the font (which is already in the native template) within the code of Joomla 2.5 to insert the icon next to the title of a menu'. Thank you very much for the help...
Simone

Answer (score 0):

Far from a stupid question, this is the method I use.

See the post from [Mark Vink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774909/mark-vink) at [Add custom element to home menu item in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073438/add-custom-element-to-home-menu-item-in-joomla/13073863#13073863) .

See also my comment on the same post for details on how to make a template overide for /modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php

Good luck!